# Assigning default namespace in networkx.write_gexf

Tags: python, networkx

Give this bit of code that python's networkx library generates as a valid GEXF file, I cannot find anywhere in the docs where I change the xmlns:ns0 to be instead xmlns:viz... the GEXF compliant namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><gexf xmlns:ns0="http://www.gexf.net/1.1draft/viz"     
version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.gexf.net/1.1draft" xmlns:viz="http://www.gexf.net/1.1draft/viz"    
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <graph defaultedgetype="directed" mode="static">
<attributes class="node" mode="static">
  <attribute id="0" title="origin" type="double" />
  <attribute id="1" title="size" type="integer" />
</attributes>
<nodes>
  <node id="0" label="Vijana Amani Pamoja (VAP)">
    <ns0:color b="70" g="11" r="160" />
    <ns0:size value="10" />
    <attvalues>
      <attvalue for="0" value="1.25" />
      <attvalue for="1" value="10" />
    </attvalues>
  </node>
```

Somewhere I might have overridden the VIZ part of the default namespace for networkx's write_gexf function, but I don't know where I did that either - so I am asking here.

```
networkx.write_gexf(G,f) # G is the graph and f is the file to write.
```

(EDITED):
The nodes say ns0:... and not viz:... as shown in the GEXF documents. This causes compatability problems with other GEXF libraries that use the viz parameters (and cannot find them).

Comment: `xmlns:ns0="http://www.gexf.net/1.1draft/viz"` - `xmlns:ns0` and `xmlns:viz` are both there and pointing toward `gexf/.../viz`. Have I missed something?

Comment: I edited the example- as you can see in the node part, it is using ns0 as the default namespace and not viz.

Comment: @MarcMaxson: have you found out how to change the namespace ? I run into the same problem...

Comment: i think this qualifies as a bug in networkx

Comment: networkx 2.1 seems to have changed a lot, including this bug. headers now have `xmlns:viz` instead of `xmlns:ns0` but controlling edge thickness and color is still not well documented. I did discover that if you give a node a viz:color it will inherit into the node's edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I updated "add_viz" function in class GEXFWriter in gexf.py as follows:

```
 def add_viz(self,element,node_data):
    viz=node_data.pop('viz',False)
    if viz:
        color=viz.get('color')
        if color is not None:
            e=Element("viz:color")
            e.attrib['r']=str(color.get('r'))
            e.attrib['g']=str(color.get('g'))
            e.attrib['b']=str(color.get('b'))
            if self.VERSION!='1.1':
                e.attrib['a']=str(color.get('a'))
            e.text=" "
            element.append(e)
        size=viz.get('size')
        if size is not None:
            e=Element("viz:size")
            e.attrib['value']=str(size)
            e.text=" "
            element.append(e)

        thickness=viz.get('thickness')
        if thickness is not None:
            e=Element("viz:thickness")
            e.attrib['value']=str(thickness)
            e.text=" "
            element.append(e)

        shape=viz.get('shape')
        if shape is not None:
            if shape.startswith('http'):
                e=Element("viz:shape")
                e.attrib['value']= 'image'
                e.attrib['uri']= str(shape)
            else:
                e=Element("viz:shape")
                e.attrib['value']= str(shape)
            e.text=" "
            element.append(e)

        position=viz.get('position')
        if position is not None:
            e=Element("viz:position")
            e.attrib['x']= str(position.get('x'))
            e.attrib['y']= str(position.get('y'))
            e.attrib['z']= str(position.get('z'))
            e.text=" "
            element.append(e)
    return node_data
```

This solved the compatibility problem for me with the GEXF libraries/tools that I use.

Bests,
ZP